# Chessmaster for MAC

Tags: games

Is there any cheessmaster version for mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chessmaster does not have a Mac version, but there are a few other chess programs that run on Mac, including the built-in Chess program, which you can find in the Applications folder.

Here's a partial list of Mac chess programs: http://osx.iusethis.com/tag/chess

If you're really hung up on Chessmaster, you could run it under Windows on your Mac using either virtualization (e.g. Parallels, VMWare) or Boot Camp.  You could also try running it under [CrossOver Games](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/cxgames/) -- they do not explicitly support Chessmaster, but you can try installing it manually, and there's a chance it might work.